# MS Project 2010 Get Work Items from TFS 2010 returns items not in Query

Tags: tfs

I have written a saved query in TFS 2010 to populate a project plan in MS Project 2010.  When I view the query results in the Get Work Items window in MS Project 2010, I see 99 work items.  Once I select "OK" to generated the project file, over 306 work items are returned (207 of which are in the closed state and were filtered out in my saved query).

Has anyone else experience this issue?  It seems that MS Project 2010 returns all related worked items even those that are excluded in the TFS Query.

Answer (score 1):

That is behaviour by design. The MS Project connector pulls down all child work items too. I experienced this also.

If you don't like this, and want it to be changed, you can raise an incident at [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio).

And don't forget to share the link so we can vote in favor of this.

Comment: Here is the incident link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/638910/ms-project-2010-get-work-items-from-tfs-2010-returns-items-not-in-query